# New VB.NET function signature behavior in Visual Studio 2012/2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, overloading, visual-studio-2013, optional-parameters

I found some interesting behavior with how VB.NET handles function signatures.  This new behavior started in VS2012 and continues to persist in VS2013.

Consider the following code segment:

```
Class test
    Function a(x As String, Optional y As Boolean = False) As String
        Return "function a() was called"
    End Function

    Function a(x As String) As String
        Return "second function a() was called"
    End Function
End Class
```

My first thought is that this will not compile, which is true in VS2010 and earlier versions.  However, VS2012 and VS2013 compiles the code without even a warning.  If you then run the following:

```
Dim x As New test()
MsgBox(x.a("123"))
```

The message indicates that the function without the optional parameter is called.

Is there a way to turn this behavior off?  It would seem that this could open the door to a developer unknowingly adding functions with the same name as other functions that have optional parameters, causing undesirable redirects.

Comment: You should really give up the habit of using the `MsgBox` function which is only there for compatibility reasons when migrating from old VB6 code. `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(...)` is the way to go.

Comment: As David R mentioned in his answer, C# has the same behaviour. So if this change eliminates differences between VB.NET and C# I consider it as a good change.

Comment: The argument just isn't optional anymore when you provide the overload.  Write sane code and all the pieces fall into place.

Comment: @AndreasAdler I agree, moving VB.NET closer to C# is a good thing.  I would still consider it an ambiguity bug, but at least it is unified between the two languages now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read Microsoft's guide on [Overload Resolution (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx) for Visual Studio 2013 and step 5 states that:

`The compiler considers the remaining overloads in pairs. For each pair, it compares the data types of the defined parameters. If the types in one of the overloads all widen to the corresponding types in the other, the compiler eliminates the latter. That is, it retains the overload that requires the least amount of widening.`

It is not explicitly stated in this article, but no widening is required to choose the function with no optional parameters. The compiler retains the second signature because it does not require widening. I cannot determine why this changed between VS2010 to VS2012 though.

This behavior *is* explicitly stated in a similar [CSharp Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

`If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I found this post after coming across the follow, what seems to me, anomaly:

```
Class SealedClass
    Public Sub Test(Param1 As String)
        'Some code
    End Sub
    Public Sub Test(Param1 As String, Optional Param2 As String = "")
        'Some other code
    End Sub
End Class

MustInherit Class BaseClass
    MustOverride Sub Test(ByVal Param1 As String)
    MustOverride Sub Test(ByVal Param1 As String, Optional ByVal Param2 As String = "")
End Class

Class SubClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    Public Overrides Sub Test(Param1 As String)
        'Some code
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub Test(Param1 As String, Optional Param2 As String = "")
        'Some other code
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the above code, `SealedClass` compiles just fine, as per the above commentary.

However, although `BaseClass` compiles, `SubClass` bleets that `Sub Test` in `BaseClass` with the optional parameter must be overridden.

To me, that's inconsistent. Does anyone have any input? Obviously the above code is merely for illustration; my own code is attempting to provide overloads for database creation with parameters such as port number, authentication, etc.